# Can "table of type" be manipulated in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, types

I have table of object type defined like this

```
create type user_role_ty as object (
    username           varchar2(32),
    role_nam           varchar2(32)
);
create type user_role_nt as table of user_role_ty
/
```

And output variable in function

```
p_user_role_list  out    bt_ww_user_role_nt
```

After filling with

```
select user_role_ty (username, role_nam)
    bulk collect into p_user_role_list
(...)
```

How can I modify this variable of table type? I would like to remove some lines, e.g. main admin may see all, local admin shall not see main admins, user may see himself only etc. Shortened:

```
if is_vendor( ... ) then
    NULL;
elsif is_admin( ... ) then
    delete from p_user_role_list
    where username in ( (...) user_name_list );
else
    delete from p_user_role_list
    where username <> p_username;
```

Simply does not work. There are several possibilities, none of which is straightforward:

- Use copy-paste the same identical original select several times which slight condition modification use. Works, but awful (plus risk of future entered bugs).
- Use `execute immediate` which I really hate - PL/SQL is great to integrate scripting language and SQL (e.g. syntax highlighting). `execute immediate` degradates PL/SQL to call SQL by string in any language (comparing to those it lacks many features).
- Use temporary table, which content will be then copied to table-type variable. This is superfluous no-use code rubbish (code shall be readable and make sense).

Is there any other way?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#LNPLS00508

Answer (score 2):

I'd filter the select query that provides the data, something like:

```
select user_role_ty (username, role_nam)
    bulk collect into p_user_role_list
from   user_role_table
where  case when is_vendor(...) = 'Y' then role_nam
            when is_admin(...) = 'Y' and role_nam in (<list of roles that the is_admin user is allowed to see>)
                 then role_nam
       end = role_nam
or     username = p_username;
```

Comment: This is the most straightforward.solution. That's the difference between information and knowledge. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The previous suggestions are spot on (do as much of the work as you can in SQL, or go "deeper" and set up Virtual Private Database roles). But if you do happen to (or need to) stick with a PL/SQL-focused solution, remember that once you have bulk collected into that collection, it is a PL/SQL variable.

So I wouldn't be thinking about using EXECUTE IMMEDIATE or a temporary table, so much as writing PL/SQL logic to apply whatever complex rules you have.

```
DECLARE
   p_user_role_list   user_role_ty;
BEGIN
   SELECT user_role_ty (username, role_nam)
     BULK COLLECT INTO p_user_role_list
     FROM (SELECT 'steven' username, 'admin' role_nam FROM DUAL);

   FOR indx IN 1 .. p_user_role_list.COUNT
   LOOP
      /* Apply changes like .DELETE to remove an element
         or even copy the elements you want to keep to
         a new collection */
      NULL;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

PS - I can understand hating to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE if you don't really need to, but when you do need to execute dynamic SQL, it certainly offers a nice, simple, native way to get the job done!

Comment: Steve, if this is really you, shouldn't your rep score be more like 68k ?  ;-) Anyway, nice to see you on SO !

Comment: Thanks, tbone. Yes, it is me, as in the SF who wrote those books on PL/SQL. I suppose I should have a higher score. But to do that I would have to spend lots more time on SO - and then I would have a higher score but other perfectly excellent Oracle Database developers would have lower scores. And that doesn't seem right. :-)

Comment: Haha!  I have your books btw, excellent work, they helped me tremendously.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution is to apply VPD policies to the underlying tables (the bit you have hidden in `(...)`. That way the PL/SQL collection can only be populated with the data the user is allowed to see.

Fine-grained access control is pretty powerful. Also, being baked into Oracle, is way more reliable than our hand-rolled code. [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e36292/vpd.htm#DBSEG007).

Comment: Sorry, I had probably used another than user/roles example. The users are defined for application outside Oracle and do not (shall not) even know about Oracle. 
The user roles do not limit access to data in Oracle, but rather different blocks etc. Using Oracle security system was found not to be consistent with our requirements (too complex on one side, too narrow on other).